# Spring boot Filter implementation for content type "multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, servlet-filters

How to implement the filter for multipart/form-data content type, I did it for application/json and it's working fine but struglinging with implementing it for multipart/form-data type of requests, below is the code for application/json. Do I have to write a different filter for it or I can manage it in the same filter, I appreciate it if someone would tell me how to do it in a proper way.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class XSSFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    filterChain.doFilter(
        new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest), servletResponse);
  }
}
```

---

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.safety.Safelist;

public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
  private final String requestJsonString;
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    super(httpServletRequest);

    try {
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      bufferedReader = httpServletRequest.getReader();
      char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      requestJsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
      JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(requestJsonString);
      processJsonNode(jsonNode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        bufferedReader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
    return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(requestJsonString.getBytes());
  }

  @Override
  public BufferedReader getReader() {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
  }

  private void processJsonNode(JsonNode jsonNode) {
    if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
      jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> processJsonNode(entry.getValue()));
    } else if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
      jsonNode.elements().forEachRemaining(this::processJsonNode);
    } else {
      sanitize("key", jsonNode.asText());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = super.getHeaderNames();
    Collections.list(headerNames)
        .forEach(headerName -> sanitize(headerName, getHeader(headerName)));
    return headerNames;
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {
    String[] parameterValues = super.getParameterValues(parameter);
    Arrays.stream(parameterValues).forEach(value -> sanitize(parameter, value));
    return parameterValues;
  }

  public void sanitize(String key, String value) {
    Safelist safelist = Safelist.none();
    Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase(Jsoup.clean(value, "", safelist, outputSettings))) {
      throw new SecurityException(
          "XSS attack error, by the key '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'");
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
 import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
    import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class ServletInputStreamWrapper extends ServletInputStream {
    
      private final byte[] data;
      private int idx = 0;
    
      public ServletInputStreamWrapper(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
      }
    
      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
        if (idx >= data.length) {
          return -1;
        }
        return data[idx++];
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean isFinished() {
        return false;
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean isReady() {
        return false;
      }
    
      @Override
      public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {}
    }
```

Comment: @BalusC I'm definitely trying on my own but I come to stack over only when I find some difficulties and I've already gone through the solution you've shared and it's useless to me, I'm not here to pass the time. I only use stack overflow when I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the functionality within `XSSRequestWrapper` by checking content type header value from `HttpServletRequest` and apply the logic for `multipart/form-data`  and `application/json` separately.

```
if (MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE.equals(httpServletRequest.getContentType())) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) httpServletRequest;
    Map<String, MultipartFile> multiParts =  multipartHttpServletRequest.getFileMap();

} else if (APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.equals(httpServletRequest.getContentType())) {

}
```

Comment: content-type check  is not an issue, I want the request body in the wrapper class, and below is the request
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/filter?paramOne=1212121212212&paramTwo=dfsdfsdfsdf' \
--header 'headOne: werte345345' \
--header 'headTwo: 345345345grg' \
--form 'multipartkey="{\"l1\": \"v1\",\"l2\": \"v2\"}"'

Comment: yeah, then the request should be type of `MultipartHttpServletRequest`, then you can read the request body as a map?